# Volley doesnot connect with flask server

Tags: android, flask, android-volley

My java code is not connect with flask. It doesn't give any error or response. Program run infinitely.
When i try to connect it is not going on response or on error function. After completing function call it start running and never stop.

Java Code:

```
Button button;
    RequestQueue rQueue;
    String url ="http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    }

    public void predict(View view){
        UploadTwoImages();
    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }

    public void UploadTwoImages() {
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.logo);

        final String imageOne = getStringImage(icon);

        final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Registration is in Process Please wait...");
        pDialog.show();

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                Log.d("JSONResult", s);
                try {
                    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(s);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

            }
        }) {
            //adding parameters to send
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                parameters.put("image", imageOne);
                return parameters;
            }
        };

        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                90000,
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        request.setShouldCache(false);
        rQueue.add(request);
    }
```

Flask Server Code:

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.files:
            output={}
            image = request.files["image"]
            print(request.files)
            basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
            file_path = os.path.join(
            basepath, 'uploads', secure_filename(image.filename))
            print(image.filename)
            image.save(file_path)
            return str([1])
    return "Error"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

url = ipv4address:portNumber/apiName

Comment: **Note:** Flask is running on local machine through localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android manifest add following 2 lines and it works for me.
`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`